# How to run test cases from the browser in cakephp

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, simpletest

I'm new to testing, so please forgive me for this question

In the cakephp manual under the "Creating tests" chapter, one can read

> When you have created a test case, you can execute it by browsing to http://your.cake.domain/cake_folder/test.php (depending on how your specific setup looks) and clicking App test cases, and then click the link to your specific file.

I don't understand the url, and how to apply to my case.

I'd like to run the following test case stored at: /app/tests/cases/models/box.test.php

My domain is www.box.local

I don't understand what url should I enter? Please enlighten me.

Comment: For other newbies, don't use SimpleTest 1.1alpha or you'll face errors like, "undefined method CakeCliReporter::SimpleReporter()" or "undefined method CakeHtmlReporter::SimpleReporter()", use SimpleTest 1.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Cake app there are two important files in /app/webroot/: `index.php` and `test.php`. Normal requests are all handled by the `index.php` file. To run tests, you have to invoke the `test.php` file. As such, if you are normally visiting the URL `www.box.local/`, just go to `www.box.local/test.php`. If your Cake app is in a sub folder and the normal URL is `www.box.local/cakeapp/`, use `www.box.local/cakeapp/test.php`.

The actual tests you launch from the interface there.